# React test library for check element in child component from parent component

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I am not able to check the existence of elements in the child component using react test library.

### Parent component as follows

This is a conditional rendering of the child component depends on the length of the location array. If the array length is greater than zero render the child component otherwise null. I want to check the existence of the `<p>` tag in the child component by its role.

```
 import ChildComponent from './ChildComponent';
 const locationResponse = [
  {
    id: 1,
    locationName: 'On Truck',
    locationDesc: 'On Truck Carrier goods',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    locationName: 'In Warehouse',
    locationDesc: 'In Warehouse',
  },
  ];
  const ParentComponent = () =>
    {
     const [location, setLocation] = useState(locationResponse);
     return (<>
     {location.length >0 ?
       <ChildComponent/> : null
      }
     </>
    );
  }
```

### child component as follows

This is a conditional rendering of the child component depends on the length of the location array. If the array length is greater than zero render the child component otherwise null . I want to check the existence of the `<p>` tag in the child component by its role.

```
    const ChildComponent = () =>
      {
        return (<>
           <p role = "datashow">Child element</p>
          </>
       );
    }
```

### My test case is given below

```
    import ParentComponent from './ParentComponent';
    test('Clicking go button purchase order list', async () => {
    render(<ParentComponent />);
    expect(screen.getByRole('datashow'));
    });
```

I got these errors after running my test case.

> TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an accessible element with the role "datashow"

Anybody help for solving these issue.

Answer (score 2):

As the error suggests, `datashow` is not a valid role. An example of a valid accessible role would be `input`, `button`, `heading` and so on. Since `<p>` has no real role, I would suggest using `getByText` instead:

```
test('Clicking go button purchase order list', async () => {
  render(<ParentComponent />);
  expect(screen.getByText('Child element').toBeInTheDocument());
});
```